# Can a parent child relationship be modeled in the same table using Foreign Keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, sql-server-2012

I am designing a table that currently looks like this:

```
Container
    ContaienrId
    ParentContainerId
    LotsOfOtherColumns
```

The idea is that a container can have a parent (which can in turn have a parent...).  Also, several containers could have the same parent.

I can just stick the ID in there, but I would like the parent to be accessible via Entity Framework.  For that to happen, I need a Foreign Key.  (I also want the protection of a FK violation if an invalid number is entered for ParentContainerId.)

But when I try to put the Foreign key on these columns I get this error:

> The columns in table 'Container (Container)' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint.

I get what it is saying, I cant use ParentContainerId unless I put a UNIQUE constraint on it.  But several containers can have the same parent, so that won't work.

**Is there a way to use one table and have a Foreign Keyed parent child relationship?**

Comment: I think it means that your FK should _point at_ a PK/UNIQUE column. _That_ would make sense. There's no point for a FK to be UNIQUE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just think you have to put a unique constraint on the ContainerId not the parentID

Comment: I feel kind of dumb... That was it!  After I switch which one was the FK column it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this if you want to model a one-to-many relationship:

```
create table container( 
    container_id int not null,
    parent_container_id int,
    more_data varchar,
    primary key(container_id),
    foreign key (parent_container_id) references container (container_id)
);
```

If you create an additional

```
unique(parent_container_id)
```

constraint, you will allow at most one child container in each parent container.